# Proxy pattern java?

Tags: design-patterns, proxy

I have these classes in Java:

```
public interface WeatherInformationServiceInterface {
    public double getTemperature(Date date, City city);
}

public class WeatherInformationService implements WeatherInformationServiceInterface {
    @Override
    public double getTemperature(Date date, City city) {
        //Depending on system configuration you will get this information from 
        //jsonservice or a xml service
        if ("JSONService".equals(configurationVariable)) {
            //call JSONService
        } else if ("XMLService".equals(configurationVariable)) {
            //call XMLService
        }
    }
}
```

My thoughts of this design is poor because:

- If in the future another service is added to the system(RMI service for example to get the temperature), I will have to modify this class and this
  violates the OPEN/CLOSE principle
- This is not real business logic, I mean, evaluate if I have to call a JSON service or XML service

My alternative design would be like this:

```
public class WeatherInformationService implements WeatherInformationServiceInterface {
    private WeatherInformationProxyService proxyService;

    @Override
    public double getTemperature(Date date, City city){    
        return proxyService.getTemperature(Date date, City city);    
    }
}

public class WeatherInformationProxyService implements WeatherInformationServiceInterface{

    @Override
    public double getTemperature(Date date, City city) {
        //Depending on system configuration you will get this information from 
        //jsonservice or a xml service
        if ("JSONService".equals(configurationVariable)) {
            //call JSONService
        } else if ("XMLService".equals(configurationVariable)) {
            //call XMLService
        }
    }
}
```

The second design would be better because:

- You focus on real business logic in the class `WeatherInformationService` and you delegate the proxy logic to `WeatherInformationProxyService`, so this would comply the SRP (single responsibility principle) and then OPEN/CLOSED principle
- If you have to add other other possible service to get the temperature, you don't have to modify the `WeatherInformationService` class, just the `WeatherInformationProxyService`

The second design:

- would be a PROXY pattern or similar? What do you think?
- I don't like the fact that I have to modify the `WeatherInformationProxyService` if I want to add another service where to get the temperature from (this violates the OPEN/CLOSED principle). Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by going full SRP. You can create multiple implementations based on XML, JSON, or whatever way your webservice is implemented in.

```java
public class WeatherInformationJsonImpl implements WeatherInformationService {

    @Override
    public double getTemperature(Date date, City city) {
        // Get the temprature from the JSON Service
    }
}

public class WeatherInformationXmlImpl implements WeatherInformationService {

    @Override
    public double getTemperature(Date date, City city) {
        // Get the temprature from the XML Service
    }
}
```

Then you can just create an instance(s) of the implementations and inject it into your service consumer.

```java
public class WeatherInformationProvider {

    private WeatherInformationService service;

    public double gimmeSomeDigits(Date date, City city) {
        return service.getTemperature(date, city);
    }

    public void setWeatherInformationService(WeatherInformationService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Now, instead of taking care of a `configurationVariable`, you can just create multiple implementations and rely on them as a single source of information.

Comment: I thought about it but,  how to do it this value configurationVariable is in some database and it can be changed at any moment because its a user configuration variable

Comment: @user3254515 then you can use some kind of strategy pattern where you just decide what implementation to use.